# Remove CSS3 background-size with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery to set a background image to stretch inside a div by using `$("#container").css("background-size", "100% 100%")`.

It works great, but then on a click of a button I want to remove the property and reset the background size to it's default state, so I am using `$("#container").removeAttr("background-size");`, and it doesn't work... nothing changes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.removeAttr()`, as its name implies, is for HTML DOM attributes, not CSS properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. `removeAttr` removes an attribute of the element not of the `css`.

```
  $("#container").css('background-size', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

`.removeAttr( attributeName )` just removes an attribute from each element in the set of matched elements.
So you should reset your CSS by `.css('background-size', '')`

Answer (score 0):

`removeAttr()` is for removing HTML attributes, not CSS styles.

You can just use the same jQuery script you're using to set the background size to auto.

`$("#container").css("background-size", "auto")`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class instead of an inline style:

```
.background-size { background-size:'100% 100%' }
```

In then this:

```
$("#container").addClass("background-size");
```

And then when you want to remove it:

```
$("#container").removeClass("background-size");
```